# TURN relay with TCP

Tags: tcp

How exactly does a TURN relay work on TCP?

Let's say User A with a server reflexive address a1:a2 sends an allocate request to the TURN Server which then allocates t1:t2 and opens a connection between t1:t2 and a1:a2, how can User B connect to t1:t2 to relay data to user A?

I think I might have misunderstood how TURN works - any clarification would be helpful!

Comment: are you facing problem in cisco expresswat ??

Comment: @Gadeliow No, I'm just trying to implement a modified version of STUN/TURN/ICE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example t1:t2 would be globally accessible (t1 IP address is a public one). So UserB would know where to send packets from the network layer. Also UserA can make a fixup for SIP signalling if it's capable to fetch bindings (a1:a2 -> t1:t2 from TURN server).

The client may also set one of the external address/port destinations to be the active destination.
After the active destination has been set:

- The TURN server forwards packets originating from the active address/port directly to the
  client, without TURN packet encapsulation.
- When the TURN server receives nonencapsulated packets from the client, the TURN server
  forwards those messages to the active destination. ((C) Video and Voice conferencing fundamentals by Scott Firestone)

You may take a look here http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2012/04/17/understanding_2d00_nat_2d00_when_2d00_setting_2d00_up_2d00_lync_2d00_part_2d00_2_2d00_stun_2d00_and_2d00_turn_2d00_explained.aspx or here https://profcollab.wordpress.com/2015/08/27/nat-and-firewall-traversal-for-sip-and-h-323/ for some explanation.
Essentially TRURN server works as an address restricted NAT.